# Extraer valores a partir de checkbox en Django

Tags: html, python, django

les comento cuál es mi problema:

Tengo que descargar los datos de una tabla guardada en django que la completan distintos usuarios. Quiero descargar los datos de sólo ciertos usuarios, por lo que creé un template con checkbox para los usuarios y, luego de eso, utilizar los checkbox marcados como un filtro para la función que me descarga los datos.

Acá está el template:

```
<form action="{% url 'descargar_excel' %}" method="POST">

 {% csrf_token %}

 <div class="descarga">
  {% for user in users %}
   <div class="div-descarga user-dercarga">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value={{user}}> {{user}} </label>
   </div>
  {% endfor %}
 </div>

 <div class="row col-15 justify-content-end pr-0">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Descargar datos</button>
 </div>
    
</form>
```

La pregunta es cómo puedo extraer esos valores seleccionados. En views.py intenté con:

```
def exportar_excel(request):

 if "checkbox" in request.POST:
  lista=request.POST.getlist('checkbox')
```

Pero no me genera la lista que estoy buscando, que es un lista con todos los values de los checkbox marcados.

Si alguno puede darme una mano, sería de gran ayuda.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola David, puedes empezar por poner `<input type="checkbox" value="{{ user}}" name="selected_users">`.
De esta manera podrás luego hacer en tus views `request.POST.getlist('selected_users')`

Comment: Sube la función GET para extraer los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Ese tipo de filtros es mucho mas facil hacerlos agregano la dependencia [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
O bien puedes envíar los datos utilizando Jquery a al view usando Ajax.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/393866)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).